# Strange File Appeared In My Home Folder

Tags: finder, user-account, file, history

I just discovered a strange file in my home folder. 
It is titled: -
The entire contents are the word: ok
on the first line & a blank second line.
There is no extension.
It was created this past Monday at 4:55pm & last modified/opened at 4:56.

How can I find out what created this? Should I be concerned? How can I find what other files, invisible or otherwise, might have been created around that same time on Monday?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly harmless. If you select a file on the desktop (even unintentionally) and press enter and then type ok - that would explain the naming.

I would open the terminal app (/Applications/Utilities) and type file and then drag the questionable file into the window and press enter.

That will look at the file contents and give you a hint about what it might contain. Spotlight information could help find other files around the same time, but I'd start with the `file` tool and get more information or just delete the file named OK - especially if you have a backup where you could get back what you lost if you find out later it was an image or document you needed.